# Why doesn't Cases match all instances of XMLElement, given Infinity levelspec?

Tags: pattern-matching, xml

Why doesn't `Cases` match all instances of `XMLElement`, given `Infinity` levelspec?

```
Column@ Cases[
Import["http://www.weather.gov/data/current_obs/KOAK.xml","XMLObject"],
XMLElement[tag:_,_,value:_]:> (tag-> value),Infinity
] 

(* ==>
credit->{NOAA's National Weather Service}
credit_URL->{http://weather.gov/}
url->{http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif}
title->{NOAA's National Weather Service}
link->{http://weather.gov}
image->{XMLElement[url,{},{http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif}],XMLElement[title,{},{NOAA's National Weather Service}],XMLElement[link,{},{http://weather.gov}]}
suggested_pickup->{15 minutes after the hour}
suggested_pickup_period->{60}
location->{Oakland, CA}
station_id->{KOAK}
latitude->{37.7}
longitude->{-122.22}
observation_time->{Last Updated on Apr 11 2012, 12:53 pm PDT}
observation_time_rfc822->{Wed, 11 Apr 2012 12:53:00 -0700}
weather->{Mostly Cloudy}
temperature_string->{60.0 F (15.6 C)}
temp_f->{60.0}
temp_c->{15.6}
relative_humidity->{62}
wind_string->{Southwest at 13.8 MPH (12 KT)}
wind_dir->{Southwest}
wind_degrees->{220}
wind_mph->{13.8}
wind_gust_mph->{0.0}
wind_kt->{12}
wind_gust_kt->{0}
pressure_string->{1014.2 mb}
pressure_mb->{1014.2}
pressure_in->{29.95}
dewpoint_string->{46.9 F (8.3 C)}
dewpoint_f->{46.9}
dewpoint_c->{8.3}
windchill_string->{58 F (14 C)}
windchill_f->{58}
windchill_c->{14}
visibility_mi->{10.00}
icon_url_base->{http://weather.gov/images/fcicons/}
two_day_history_url->{http://www.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KOAK.html}
icon_url_name->{bkn.jpg}
ob_url->{http://www.weather.gov/data/METAR/KOAK.1.txt}
disclaimer_url->{http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html}
copyright_url->{http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html}
privacy_policy_url->{http://weather.gov/notice.html}
current_observation->{XMLElement[credit,{},{NOAA's National Weather Service}],XMLElement[credit_URL,{},{http://weather.gov/}],XMLElement[image,{},{XMLElement[url,{},{http://weather.gov/images/xml_logo.gif}],XMLElement[title,{},{NOAA's National Weather Service}],XMLElement[link,{},{http://weather.gov}]}],XMLElement[suggested_pickup,{},{15 minutes after the hour}],XMLElement[suggested_pickup_period,{},{60}],XMLElement[location,{},{Oakland, CA}],XMLElement[station_id,{},{KOAK}],XMLElement[latitude,{},{37.7}],XMLElement[longitude,{},{-122.22}],XMLElement[observation_time,{},{Last Updated on Apr 11 2012, 12:53 pm PDT}],XMLElement[observation_time_rfc822,{},{Wed, 11 Apr 2012 12:53:00 -0700}],XMLElement[weather,{},{Mostly Cloudy}],XMLElement[temperature_string,{},{60.0 F (15.6 C)}],XMLElement[temp_f,{},{60.0}],XMLElement[temp_c,{},{15.6}],XMLElement[relative_humidity,{},{62}],XMLElement[wind_string,{},{Southwest at 13.8 MPH (12 KT)}],XMLElement[wind_dir,{},{Southwest}],XMLElement[wind_degrees,{},{220}],XMLElement[wind_mph,{},{13.8}],XMLElement[wind_gust_mph,{},{0.0}],XMLElement[wind_kt,{},{12}],XMLElement[wind_gust_kt,{},{0}],XMLElement[pressure_string,{},{1014.2 mb}],XMLElement[pressure_mb,{},{1014.2}],XMLElement[pressure_in,{},{29.95}],XMLElement[dewpoint_string,{},{46.9 F (8.3 C)}],XMLElement[dewpoint_f,{},{46.9}],XMLElement[dewpoint_c,{},{8.3}],XMLElement[windchill_string,{},{58 F (14 C)}],XMLElement[windchill_f,{},{58}],XMLElement[windchill_c,{},{14}],XMLElement[visibility_mi,{},{10.00}],XMLElement[icon_url_base,{},{http://weather.gov/images/fcicons/}],XMLElement[two_day_history_url,{},{http://www.weather.gov/data/obhistory/KOAK.html}],XMLElement[icon_url_name,{},{bkn.jpg}],XMLElement[ob_url,{},{http://www.weather.gov/data/METAR/KOAK.1.txt}],XMLElement[disclaimer_url,{},{http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html}],XMLElement[copyright_url,{},{http://weather.gov/disclaimer.html}],XMLElement[privacy_policy_url,{},{http://weather.gov/notice.html}]}
*)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason your approach fails is because `Cases` works slightly differently than what you've intended in the question. `Cases` does a depth-first scanning and once it finds its first match, it transforms it and starts traversing the tree backwards, looking for other matches. Consider this simple example:

```
list = {p[1, 2], q, {p[3, 4], p[5, p[6, 7]]}};
Cases[list, p[a_, b_] :> f[a, b], Infinity]
(* Out[1]= {f[1, 2], f[3, 4], f[6, 7], f[5, p[6, 7]]} *)
```

You can see that all 4 instances of `p[_, _]` are found by `Cases`, but the rule replacement is only done to the output before returning — i.e., the tree is not modified in place — so when it walks back up a node, it does not see the replacement to the deeper `p[_, _]` because the tree was never modified.

The `TreeForm` below gives an idea of how the last two matches are handled. The third match is the deepest one, `p[6, 7]` which returns `f[6, 7]` and in the second one, the one just above it is matched without modifying the inner `p[_, _]` (because that's the replacement rule given).

[image]
[image]

This is exactly the case in your situation, where one `XMLElement` has another within it.

One possible solution is to extract them all first with `Cases` and then use `ReplaceRepeated`:

```
Cases[list, _p, Infinity] //. p[a_, b_] :> f[a, b]
(* Out[2]= {f[1, 2], f[3, 4], f[6, 7], f[5, f[6, 7]]} *)
```

So for the example in the question, it would be:

```
Cases[Import["http://www.weather.gov/data/current_obs/KOAK.xml","XMLObject"],
XMLElement, _XMLElement, Infinity] //. XMLElement[tag:_, _, value:_] :> (tag -> value)
```

---

As Albert Retey rightly points out (also, thanks to him for the helpful suggestions and corrections), what `Cases` does with a rule replacement is the same as `Cases` with no rule, followed by `ReplaceAll`:

```
Cases[list, _p, Infinity] /. p[a_, b_] :> f[a, b]
```

whereas `ReplaceRepeated` is what's needed here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm somewhat pedantic, but the nice improvements in your explanation made me fully understand it and realizing it might not be entierly correct. All four appearances of `p[_,_]` -- including the orange one -- are actually found, just count the entries in the output. Maybe it will be even more instructive to use `list={p[1, 2], q, {p[3, 4], p[x, p[5, 6]]}}`. What `Cases` with a rule does is like what it does with no rule followed by ReplaceAll, `Cases[list,p[_,_],Infinity] /. p[a_, b_] :> f[a, b]`, but the OP needs `Cases` + `ReplaceRepeated`, as you have correctly shown...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Aha! I hadn't looked carefully at the 4 outputs. So I think it would be right to say that `Cases` does the rule replacement on the unmodified tree at each step (which makes sense, because the replacement rule only says to modify the match before returning the output). I will edit my post accordingly

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica does match all instances. There is, however, one `XMLElement` (current_observation) that contains all other `XMLElement`s.  So after the deepest `XMLElement`s are matched MMA goes one step up and matches the containing `XMLElement`, which is then returned, and it shows the other `XMLElement`s.

A simple example:

```
Cases[
 {XMLElement["test", "BlahBlah", 
     {XMLElement["YAT", "Rubarber", "Ajax"], XMLElement["YATT", {}, "pipo"]}
  ]},
 XMLElement[tag : _, _, value : _] :> (tag -> value), Infinity
 ]

(*
==> {"YAT" -> "Ajax", "YATT" -> "pipo", 
 "test" -> {XMLElement["YAT", "Rubarber", "Ajax"], 
   XMLElement["YATT", {}, "pipo"]}}
*)
```

If you want to get rid of the highest `XMLElement` change the levelspec to a range excluding the top level:

```
Cases[
 {XMLElement["test", 
   "BlahBlah", {XMLElement["YAT", "Rubarber", "Ajax"], 
    XMLElement["YATT", {}, "pipo"]}]},
 XMLElement[tag : _, _, value : _] :> (tag -> value), {2, Infinity}
 ]

(*
==> {"YAT" -> "Ajax", "YATT" -> "pipo"}
*)
```

To answer your comment: you can get rid of all occurrences of `XMLElement` using `Replace`:

```
Column@Replace[
  Cases[Import["http://www.weather.gov/data/current_obs/KOAK.xml", 
    "XMLObject"], XMLElement[tag : _, _, value : _] :> (tag -> value),
    Infinity],
  XMLElement[tag : _, _, value : _] :> (tag -> value), Infinity
  ]
```

Comment: Try this however:   `Column@ Cases[
Import["http://www.weather.gov/data/current_obs/KOAK.xml","XMLObject"],
XMLElement[tag:_,_,value:_]:> (tag-> value),{2,Infinity}
]`